# "Intel(R) Graphics Installer for Linux" for Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, 14.10, intel-graphics

I know that my Intel drivers are out of date, but I am unsure of exactly how to get them up-to-date, because when I was running Windows 7 I was able to run Intel's "Intel® Driver Update Utility" which would automatically find the right Intel drivers for my system and then install them.

But this "Intel® Driver Update Utility" is only available on Windows, so I would have to use a different solution on Linux.

I did some further research and found out that there is an open-source "Intel(R) Graphics Installer for Linux" which I can install from: [Linux GraphicsIntel(R) - Graphics Installer for Linux* 1.0.7](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7)

I read about this open-source software here: [Latest Intel Linux Graphics Drivers Now Available on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/intel-graphics-installer-linux-updated-1-0-6)

But was disappointed to find that this software seems only to be available on Ubuntu for 14.04: [Intel Graphics Installer Updated, No Longer Makes Xorg Go Kaboom](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/11/intel-linux-graphics-driver-installer-update) Yet the link says that:

```
Support for Ubuntu 14.10 is likely to arrive with the release of the 2014Q4 stack, due in December
```

But when visiting the ["Intel(R) Graphics Installer for Linux"](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7)'s website which I mentioned above, it says that the latest version is `1.0.7` which is the version which in the other [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/11/intel-linux-graphics-driver-installer-update) (that I mentioned above) it states that that version only supports 14.04 in Ubuntu.

So really what my question is, can I get a version of this software which supports Ubuntu 14.10, and if not then when will the version which does support 14.10 be released? Are there any versions still in development which I can try out that would work on 14.10?

Comment: My question is *why* do you need to update your Drivers?  If everything is working, why do you need to update?  The problem with updating is that you could very easily break things if you aren't careful.  (In theory, software supporting 14.04 supports 14.10, but for the reasons above, I question why you need to update in the first place)

Comment: @ThomasW.: Well I am having problems with my graphics drivers, so I thought that I should try updating them. It may also be more secure to update things like networking drivers.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that unless your network drivers are proprietary you don't need to update those as frequently. As for your graphics drivers, you could *try* to use the "Graphics Installer for Linux" for 14.04, but I believe the reason they support 14.04 and not 14.10 is because 14.10 has a much shorter lifespan - it is only supported for a very short period of time, as [this diagram from the Ubuntu LTS Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ubuntu-release-cycle-2.png) shows and since 14.10 EOLs in July, that's probably another reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version of the driver update software was finally released which supports Ubuntu 14.10. It can be installed from here: [Linux GraphicsIntel(R) - Graphics Installer for Linux* 1.0.8](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2015/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.8)